# How can I copy reddit's post view where clicking on a post opens in a modal and changes URL or opens in a full page by accessing the URL directly?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, modal-dialog, reddit

This baffles me particularly as it's the same URL. I'm developing a Reddit style clone in angular.

I can do this approach with slightly different URLs, by appending something like /modal on the end but not with the same url.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Angular - Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) particularly the `go` method.

Basically:

- On your main page when you open a post in a modal, use `go` to update the URL to `post/42`.
- In your routes, when given the `post/42` URL, just load a full page component instead of the modal.

Comment: Thanks so much! I found that `Location.go()` was exactly what i wanted!

Comment: Great. Yeah, you're right that way the user can go back again. I'll update the answer.